# How would I be able to use a font awesome icon as a user's avatar?

Tags: filters, users, user-meta, avatar, fonts

Would it be possible to use/allocate a font awesome icon as a user's avatar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would.

You can use [`get_avatar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_avatar) filter and display whatever you want as avatar. Here's an example:

```
function my_custom_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {
    $user = false;

    if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {

        $id = (int) $id_or_email;
        $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );

    } elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) ) {

        if ( ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ) {
            $id = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
            $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
        }

    } else {
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );   
    }

    if ( $user && is_object( $user ) ) {

        if ( $user->data->ID == '1' ) {
            $avatar = '<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        }

    }

    return $avatar;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'my_custom_avatar', 10, 5 );
```

It will show user icon as avatar for user with ID == 1.

Of course it would make much more sense, if the icon was stored as some user meta and so on. But this should be some start...

Comment: How would I add multiple users and their icons to this?

Comment: @Pete it is fired up for every user. The `if ( $user->data->ID == '1' ) {` checks if it is user with ID = 1 and modifies only his avatar. So you have to change this part of code to whatever you need.

Comment: OK but I want multiple users to keep their icon then I need multiple instances of the above code?